# Can I host asp.net webform web application on services fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am researching about azure service fabric and found nothing about how to host asp.net webform web application on service fabric? My application is built on asp.net version 4 and it is a monolithic app not microdevices based. Is it possible to host on service fabric?

Comment: SF supports containers, so you could containerize your webforms application. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-overview#scenarios-for-using-containers

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET webforms uses the System.Web assembly which is coupled to IIS. Service fabric uses OWIN for self-hosting the ASP.NET web apps. Thus, it is not possible to host asp.net webforms inside service fabric.